# Replace semi-colon with comma

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace a semi-colon with a comma in a range.

The following code only deletes the semi-colon, it doesn't put the comma in its place.

```
  Range("AU2:AU250").Select
  Selection.Replace What:=";", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: What kind of data is in the cells where you're replacing the semicolons?

Comment: It's data in a CSV file.  The particular range I am working with is numbers imported as text.  The semi-colons are between a group of numbers and I need to replace them all with commas.

Comment: If you mean as thousands separators, that should be done through formatting, not as part of the cell value.

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this without stepping through each cell and replacing the semi-colons with a comma. That is the only way you will be able to add a `Chr(39)` [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) to the value before returning it to the cell. The commas are disappearing because Excel it interpreting them as part of the number and removing them from the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx).

Comment: They are not thousand separators.  I need the comma to simply replace the semi-colons.  I've been typing them in manually to this point and I want to speed up the process.  The numbers are used as SKUs in an order file.  Sometimes they are three digits and other times they are four digits.

Comment: if this is about reading in a CSV, a good one-off solution is to temporarily change the computer's locale settings (comma, thousands seperator, list character, date formats) via the Control panel, then import the CSV, then change back the computer's locale settings

Comment: and if you want to replace ALL in the CSV file, open the CSV with Notepad and press Ctrl-A then Ctrl-H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Sub Comma()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range

    Set R = Range([AU2], [AU250])

    For Each C In R.Cells
        C = Replace(C, ";", ",")
    Next C

End Sub
```

This is IMHO a more VBA like approach making use of range objects rather than simulating Excel stuff that you would use when interacting directly with your sheet

Comment: It's also a lot more inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy paste some of the offending cells from the CSV range in the csv file? Open it in wordpad though, not in excel.

Also, what version of excel are you using? I haven't managed to get this to occur either on 2003 or 2010.

And I assume you need to do this more than once is why you are making a macro or is find/replace failing and you are posting macro code to get help with that too? :-)

Comment: I'm using 2013.  The code provided above solved my issue perfectly actually.